# S3: unique link to the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a few questions about my project because I have stopped and don't know how to go on.

I create a small saas, something similar to an educational platform.
It is about access to video files for a fee.

The programming language is TypeScript: React / NestJS / PostgreSQL / Stripe / AWS S3.

My logic at the moment is as follows - if the user pays, I add the record to my database:

```
user_trainings
id | uuid | user_id | training_id
 1 | d-2a |       1 |           1
```

My simplified base structure for training looks like this:

```
trainings
id | uuid | name | video_file_name_key
 1 | d21x |  foo |      videos/boo.mp4
```

File `videos/boo.mp4` is the key of my file, which is in bucket aws s3.

So the user with id 1, after logging into my application, has access to training.
Now, how could I protect this file and the link to the file so that the user cannot share it?

I know I can enable CORS and that will potentially solve my problem, but I wish the link to this file was unique. If it is possible? Can this file be secured somehow?

How can I get a link to a file? The frontend user only has the key. I could link to the file via my server, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944290/password-protected-image-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects stored in Amazon S3 are **private by default**.

For your situation, I would recommend using [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which are time-limited URLs that grant temporary access to private objects.

The flow would be:

- A user **logs into** your application
- The user requests access to a course
- Your application checks **whether they are entitled** to access the course
- If so, the application **generates a pre-signed URL** that is valid for, say, 30 minutes
- The application returns the link to the course, or uses the pre-signed URL in a page (eg in a `<video>` tag)
- When the user clicks the link or opens the page in their browser, the browser **requests the object from S3 via the pre-signed URL**
- Amazon S3 will **verify the signature** on the pre-signed URL and confirm that it is within the validity period. If so, it returns the object to the user.
- If the validity period has expired, the pre-signed URL returns `Access Denied`

It only takes a couple of lines of code to generate a pre-signed URL and it does not require a call to AWS.

The beauty of using a pre-signed URL is that your application has full control over *who* can access the object, but Amazon S3 takes responsibility for serving the content to the user.

Comment: Presigned URLs are a good solution, but it should be noted that the user can still trivially download the file and share it elsewhere, even if the URL to it expires.

Comment: That is correct. The download will not work once the link expires, but the link could be shared and other people could access the object during the validity period. If somebody downloads the file during that period, they can of course keep it and share it however they like. That's pretty-much the nature of the Internet unless you do fancy streaming protocols (that can still be circumvented by clever people).